# SQL Server: take one table & make side by side comparison of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am accessing one of my tables and it is showing data (`vchCategory`) for an `esn` (electronic serial #) in a column on separate rows but I want to see it in the same row, how can I do that?

I want to display the `vchEsn, dtTransactionDatetime, vchCategory1, vchCategory2`

```
select *
from tblDailySalesRpt_History s
where vchEsn in (select vchEsn
                 from tblDailySalesRpt_History s
                 where vchOrigSalesMonth = 'mar 2014'
                 group by s.vchEsn
                 having count(vchesn) >= 2)
order by 1
```

This returns the following:

[image]

Comment: Please format your code properly and paste the query results in *text*

Comment: I advice you to serially consider reformat your data table and data structures. You should have one table where you save your vchEsn with a corresponding ID. A table of vchCategories and a table to relate both of them

Comment: This can be done with a PIVOT table, but that requires a hard-coded list of categories (unless you use dynamic SQL).  Do you have a complete, static list of categories or does it change over time?

Comment: The dtTransactionDatetime could be two different values for the two rows containing vchCategory1 and vchCategory2, right? Which dtTransactionDatetime would you want to select?

Comment: @ericpap: you mean "seriously", not "serially" I guess?

Comment: jajaja yes!!! sorry, my bad!

Comment: @mellamokb, I could hardcode categories, there are only 6 and they do not change.

Comment: @JosephB, I'd like to show both dtTransactionDateTimes and have the corresponding vchCategory next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect data from multiple rows together into columns by using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select
  vchEsn, [Returns], [IW New Activation], [Deactivated]
from
  (select vchEsn, dtTransactionDateTime, vchCategory from tblDailySalesRpt_History) s
pivot
(
  MAX(dtTransactionDateTime)
  FOR vchCategory in ([Returns], [IW New Activation], [Deactivated])
) pvt
order by vchEsn
```

Sample Output ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/450d1/6)):

```
|             VCHESN |                      RETURNS |            IW NEW ACTIVATION |                  DEACTIVATED |
|--------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| 256691413606894729 | March, 01 2014 11:34:24+0000 | March, 10 2014 16:20:51+0000 |                       (null) |
| 256691413607342471 | March, 12 2014 16:29:06+0000 | March, 17 2014 18:05:17+0000 |                       (null) |
| 256691413607372883 | March, 04 2014 10:46:18+0000 |                       (null) | March, 10 2014 20:01:33+0000 |
```